# How-to correctly make a Parse.com Parse.Cloud.httpRequest from the client-side?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, http-request

I'd like to make a http request from my cloudcode that gets called on my clientside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this a bit confusing at first so hopefully this helps.

**In your Cloud Code `main.js`**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("POSTfromCloud", function(request, response) {

   //runs when Parse.Cloud.run("POSTfromCloud") on the client side is called
   Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "X-Parse-Application-Id": "[PARSE_APP_ID]",
          "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "[PARSE_REST_ID]",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
       },

       //adds a new class to my parse data
       url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/newPOSTfromCloudClass/",


       body: {
               "newPOSTfromCloudClass": {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
             },

       success: function (httpResponse) {
                console.log(httpResponse.text);
                response.success(httpResponse);
       },
       error:function (httpResponse) {
                console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
                response.error(httpResponse.status);
       }

    });  //end of Parse.Cloud.httpRequest()

});
```

**On your client side**. This can be placed anywhere in any language, just use the `Parse.Cloud.run` to call the matching `Parse.Cloud.define` you placed in the cloud. You use the

```
Parse.Cloud.run('POSTfromCloud', {}, {
        success: function(result) {
          console.log("Posted a new Parse Class from Cloud Code Successfully! :"+ JSON.stringify(result))
        },
        error: function(error) {
        console.log("Oops! Couldn't POST from Cloud Code successfully..  :"+ error)
        }
      });
    }
```

**Your Result:** Assuming your POSTing
[image]

(here if you want to delete this new object your url would append the object id like so `/newPOSTfromCloudClass/60j1uyaBt` )

Know it doesnt have to be a httpRequst cloud function. You can do "anything" in the `define` and `run` functions.

**NOTE:** Also seen my other related question on passing params in this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33589322/how-to-correctly-pass-params-between-parse-cloud-code-and-the-client-httpreque)

Comment: I'm more interested in a unified way that I can make requests from the client side and deploy to Parse Cloud, knowing that it'll work exactly the same way.